# Does "彼は昼過ぎに来ます" mean "He'll come after lunch." or "He'll come in the afternoon."?

Tags: meaning, usage

Dictionary says 昼 means noon, midday, or lunch but colloquially if someone says "彼は昼過ぎに来ます" would it mean "He'll come after lunch." or "He'll come in the afternoon."?

Comment: I'm curious  which time of the day (?) _afternoon_ refers to (= when _evening_ starts).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

昼過ぎ means early afternoon. I would say between a few minutes past noon and around two at the latest. Whether you have had lunch is not important. If I wanted to say "after lunch," I wouldn't say 過ぎ. It's purely about time.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it can be both. Since 昼 can mean (as you wrote in the OP) noon, lunch, so it depends on situation. If you are planning to have lunch with someone when you meet them, you can use "*afternoon*"; if you don't plan to, you can use "*after lunch*".

I think "*afternoon*" is the most commonly used, since either way he'll come to you at afternoon anyway.

Comment: IMO “lunch” is unlikely here. “After lunch” would be something like 昼食後.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky Well, I do use this usage IRL so... Perhaps this is just me using it weirdly?

Answer (score 0):

I would translate it by

> He will come in the early afternoon

or

> He comes in the early afternoon

depending on the context to capture the meaning of 昼過ぎ.